# How can I get jQuery validate to validate multiple required textareas?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have three `<textarea>` blocks in a form, however jQuery validate is only enforcing that the first one before allowing the form to be submitted.

Each of the textareas have unique ids and I have tried to specify that they are all required:

```
<textarea id="textarea1" class="input-xlarge required" minlength="50" required="required"  >
</textarea>
```

<del>It seems to work if I don't call `jQuery('form').validate()`, however this form is being loaded dynamically so I believe I will need to explicitly bind jquery validate to the form via `jQuery('form').validate()`</del>

Here is what I've got:

http://jsfiddle.net/vjq2d/

Comment: How can it work if you don't call `.validate()`? The validate plugin only checks forms that you've explicitly told it to operate on. I think you may just be seeing the browser's built-in handling of the `required` attribute.

Comment: i had the same question. and wow - didn't even know browsers had a built-in handling of the required attribute. imagine that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that you don't have the "name" attribute on the textareas.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `rules`
you can see the **DEMO** here: http://jsfiddle.net/yosafatade/vjq2d/7/

Comment: Great - but why does it not work with the CSS class? Can I add a "rule" so that all textarea elements will be required? Trying for the MVC approach...